# How to properly use if else and else if

Tags: javascript, function, random, console.log

I am using codecademy courses and I'm learning how to make a rock paper scissors game out of randomizing numbers. It says I've done a "good job" but every time I try to properly get each one to properly show up to their respective conditions it messes up.

Please leave a comment pinpointing the error and tips on avoiding it in the future.

Conditions 
- 0 to .33 = Rock
-.34 to .66 = Paper
-.67 to 1 = Scissors

JS Code

```
var userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

console.log(computerChoice);

if  (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    console.log("Rock");
}

else if (0.34 < computerChoice < 0.66) {
   console.log("Paper");   
}

else {
    console.log("Scissors");   
}
```

Comment: The problem is on the else if you need to evaluate them separately or using &&

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(computerChoice>=0&&computerChoice<=0.33)
{
  console.log("Rock");
}
else if(computerChoice>=0.34&&computerChoice<=0.66)
{
  console.log("Paper"); 
}
else if(computerChoice>=0.67&&computerChoice<=1)
{
  console.log("Scissors");      
}
```

HI, I assume that random number you verify range on from 0 to 1.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't know you can 'else if' more than once.

Comment: You realize you're not evenly distributed here, because 0.33 is less than a third, and all the numbers between .33 and .34 default to scissors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in this line:

```
else if (0.34 < computerChoice < 0.66) {
```

Try this:

```
else if (0.35 < computerChoice && computerChoice < 0.67) {
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to read a programming book , or read some online tutorial about the loops 
anyway use the below code it will solve your problem

```
    var userChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

    var computerChoice = Math.random();

    console.log(computerChoice);

    if  (computerChoice <= 0.33) 
    {
        console.log("Rock");
    }

else if(computerChoice>=0.34&&computerChoice<=0.66)
     {
       console.log("Paper"); 
     }
else if(computerChoice>=0.67&&computerChoice<=1)
     {
       console.log("Scissors");      
     }

   else
    {
      console.log("Invalid input");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error everyone seems to make is that you can have 0.331 and that evaluates to "Scissors". The logic is more reasonable to be the following:

```
var result = (computerChoice >= 0.67 ? "Scissors" : (computerChoice >= 0.34 ? "Paper" : "Rock"));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be a tenth answerer, but all of the given answers are bad. You understand that

```
else if (0.34 < computerChoice < 0.66) {
```

is bad syntax, right? OK, so let's also solve the bias problem: 0.33 is less than a third, and all the numbers between 0.33 and 0.34 are defaulting to scissors. If you want an even distribution, the simplest way is to make a function with early exits:

```
function computerChoice() {
    var v = Math.random();

    if (v < (1.0 / 3.0)) return "rock";
    if (v < (2.0 / 3.0)) return "paper";
    return "scissors";
}
```

This is as good as double-precision floating point will allow, which is more than good enough for most purposes.

Comment: I've noticed you left out an else if/else  keyword. Are you implying that the program will just run over them and select the correct choice it picks up first?

Comment: No need for `else` here. Putting it into a function allows you to use early-returns instead. The function will, on average, only use 1.6 comparisons per call. I think it's easier to understand as well. Long strings of `if/else` can be confusing and error-prone.